How to ask microphone permission for the chrome extension
I am working on a screen recording application that would have inject content script on the page when the user clicks on the extension icon. After the user click on the extension icon, I want to ask for the microphone permission access for the chrome
Hello everyone, I am working on a chrome extension that would record user current tab screen using tab capture api. However, when I try to call the getUserMedia from the content script, it prompts a permission for the current webpage microphone access instead of the extension microphone access.
const audioStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true
});

I tested other screen recorder extension where when I first install the extension and click on the extension icon and try to record a screen, it prompts a microphone permission access for the entire extension for once and if allowed, it never ask for it again, unlike mine, where it ask for every new page.
Chrome extension permission for once
As you can see in the image, loom ask for the microphone permission for once and would never ask again on any page if allowed.
